# handle empty string case extracting a string from std::istream

Tags: c++, stl

Using the following code to extract a string from a std::istream :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void parse(std::istream & is, std::string & out)
{
    is >> out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc>1)
    {
        std::istringstream is(argv[1]);
        std::string out("__INIT__");
        std::cout << "good:"  << is.good() << " fail:"<< is.fail() <<  " eof:"<< is.eof()  << " in_avail:"<< is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << " value:" << out << std::endl;
        parse(is, out);
        std::cout << "good:"  << is.good() << " fail:"<< is.fail() <<  " eof:"<< is.eof()  << " in_avail:"<< is.rdbuf()->in_avail() << " value:" << out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

With a non-empty string the output looks like :

```
$./a.out "TEST" 
good:1 fail:0 eof:0 in_avail:4 value:__INIT__
good:0 fail:0 eof:1 in_avail:0 value:TEST
```

With an empty string the output looks like :

```
$./a.out ""
good:1 fail:0 eof:0 in_avail:0 value:__INIT__
good:0 fail:1 eof:1 in_avail:0 value:__INIT__
```

Instead of this, I would expect :

```
good:1 fail:0 eof:0 in_avail:0 value:__INIT__
good:0 fail:0 eof:1 in_avail:0 value:
```

The operator>> does not extract an empty string. The result is the same with an empty string or and no data.

Any suggestion to handle this situation will be appreciated.

Comment: `if (is.str().empty()) str.clear();`?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you explain what you wanted to happen instead of this?

Comment: I, for one, am entirely unsure of what your problem is.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: +1: _Much_ better question now with this detail. This is now a viable testcase.

Comment: Is the actual string that you supply `""` or are you not supplying a value at all?

Comment: @0x499602D2 the string is specified by argv[1] that is "". Nevertheless initializing std:istringstream("") give the same result. For string extraction, I could clear the string when number of available character in the stream is 0. But for other type I need to implement a clear method... I don't see other solution !

Comment: @mpromonet You'll have to implement your own stream class to do something like that, or you can overload `operator >>` for your own user-defined type.

Comment: @mpromonet Check my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using your `parse` function exclusively for extraction, you can simply make it out to be a check for an empty buffer. If there is, simply `clear` the string:

```
void parse(std::istream& is, std::string& out)
{
    if (is.eof() || is.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
    {
        out.clear();
        return;
    }

    is >> out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> There is no difference between an empty value and no value.

That's just your assumption, and it's not really true.

If you attempt to extract a string, it is expected that there are *characters to extract*. Before characters are available, it is impossible to perform *any* extraction, let alone one that results in extraction to a particular object.

**This is entirely expected behaviour.**

I guess your confusion stems from your prior check for `argc > 1`, but although the shell pretended `./myProgram ""` had some argument, as far as your stream is concerned *there is nothing in that argument*.

If you wish to make your own handling for it, simply stick an `if` condition on `is.fail()` after the read.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc>1)
    {
        std::istringstream is(argv[1]);
        std::string out;
        is >> out;

        if (is.fail()) {
           std::cout << "Well, you gave me an argument, but it was empty, biatch!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Don't bother checking `is.eof()`; it'll be set when you reached the end of input whether it contained any characters or not.

Comment: Shouldn't you check `good` instead? There are other causes than `eof` which can result in a failed extraction.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Isn't the OP specifically interested in whether there was nothing to extract in the first place? I think that `eof` is the perfect fit for this whereas, by contrast, there are in fact plenty of  causes other than EOF which can result in `good` being negated. I would want him to handle _those_ cases in some other manner.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it always print "Well, you gave me an argument, but it was empty, biatch!\n". Checking (is.fail() == true) answer better to the problem but the istream could set the failbit for other reason.

Comment: @mpromonet: Hmm you're right. Tested and fixed again... Really this is the best you can do unless you simply check the contents of `argv[1]` (which is a more obvious but less general solution)